# How to Install/Configure Zend Framework 2 on an Azure?

Tags: azure, zend-framework2

A client asked me **if it's possible to install zf2 on an Azure environment**. I haven't used azure yet, even if I know it's possible to configure a virtual server with linux, I'd like to know if there is a tutorial to do this or is not possible to install zf2 on Azure.

Comment: this helped me : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure supports PHP and it also supports different PHP frameworks like Zend Framework.

You can find nice blog: [Configuring Zend Framework apps for Windows Azure](http://www.dragonbe.com/2011/12/configuring-zend-framework-apps-for.html) on [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) and Azure describing database configuration, sessions, caching and many more.

I hope that will help.

Comment: Is there any comment on how to setup document root? Couldn't find any clue.